# Load dynamic data in dialog box of jquerymobile

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, jquery-mobile

I am trying to load data from server in dialog box of jquerymobile.

I open dialog box using

```
<a href="menu.htm" data-rel="dialog"  data-transition="slideup" >Menu</a>
```

and menu.htm file contains following code :

```
 <div data-role="page" id="men">
    <div data-position="inline" data-theme="d" data-role="header" class="ui-corner-top ui-overlay-shadow ui-bar-d ui-header" role="banner">
        <a data-iconpos="notext" data-rel="back" data-icon="delete" href="#" class="ui-btn-left ui-btn ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-up-d" title="Close" data-theme="d"><span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all"><span class="ui-btn-text">Close</span><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-delete ui-icon-shadow"></span></span></a>
        <h1 class="ui-title" tabindex="0" role="heading" aria-level="1">Dialog</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" data-theme="e" id="menus">
        <p>
            This is a regular page, styled as a dialog. To create a dialog, just link to a normal page and include a transition and 
            <code>
                data-rel="dialog"
            </code>
            attribute.
        </p>
        <a href="index.html#page5" data-role="button" data-theme="a">Good for you</a>
        <a href="docs-dialogs.html" data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-theme="c">Don't care, really</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I included js file and added following code that js :

```
$('div[id="men"]').live("pageshow", function(){
            alert("loaded");
    });
```

But it does not showing me the alert.

Please help me

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Move the  included js file and following code to the main script (not menu.htm) and not the dialog:

```
$('div[id="men"]').live("pageshow", function(){
    alert("loaded");
});
```